# how to save toogle class with cookies? or help me with something similar/alternative to this one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
function myFunction() {
{
   var element = document.getElementById("body");
   element.classList.toggle("bdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("theader");
   element.classList.toggle("hdark");
}
{
   var element = document.getElementById("sh");
   element.classList.toggle("shh");
}
{
  var x = document.getElementById("hs");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
}
```

```css
.bdark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.hdark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.shh {
  display: none;
}

.hs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="light">

<p id="theader">Click the "Try it" button to toggle between adding and removing the class names</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is a DIV element.
</div>

<div>
 <div id="sh" class="sh">dark black</div>
 <div id="hs" class="hs">light white</div>
</div>
```

i want it's class to be saved so when i refresh or reopen the page it would be same class as it was when i left. or some alternative code that works same.                                                                            Thanks for Reading This. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use local storage. Its very simple and better than cookies.

for example to set element bg color (on load):

```
if(localStorage.getItem("color") == "black") { 
element.classList.add("dark"); }
```

and on your function add :

```
localStorage.setItem("color",black or white )
```

Note: You should add an if statement on your function to check if class available set local storage item is set to black or not

Comment:  sorry to say but i dont know anything in javascript can you tell me how/where should i put it. If it is possible can complete the code and insert it where  it should be.

Comment: yes. ican. please give me a github URL.

Comment: sorry but i dont use git hub but uoy can contact me on :-
[whatsapp](https://wa.me/16393905391)
[telegram](https://t.me/t639393)
[instagram](https://www.instagram.com/willz.777)

Comment: but i use git hub. i send the code in here

Comment: see this gist https://gist.github.com/ama-coder/4f7f0475aac3ebe93bf028a44a8ac162

Comment: its still not working.

Comment: realy! i dont test that.

Answer (score -2):

add this to end of jquery file (Mrbg => mr babak golbaharan :) )

```
$.extend({
  MrbgSetCookie:function(name,value,days){
    var expires = '';
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
  },
  MrbgGetCookie:function(name){
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') 
        c = c.substring(1,c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
        return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
  },
  MrbgRemoveCookie:function(name){   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
  },
});
```

now you can use this for set, get and remove cookies
such as this

```
$.MrbgSetCookie( 'cookieName', 'cookieValue' , 'period in day' );
```

in this case:

```
element = document.getElementById("body");
element.classList.toggle("bdark");   
    
( element.classList.contains('bdark') )?
  $.MrbgSetCookie( yourElementID, 'bdark' , 365 ):
  $.MrbgRemoveCookie(yourElementID );
```